How to destroy particle clones after being instantiated?
I have a basic raycaster and particle spawner at the raycast. It instantiates just fine, but the clones don't delete, even if the particlesystem prefab has the "destroy on completion" checked.
[SerializeField]
ParticleSystem particles;
Quaternion playerRotation;

if(Physics.Raycast(gunRay, out RaycastHit hitInfo))
{
    hitObject = hitInfo.transform.gameObject;
    Debug.Log(hitObject.name);
    Destroy(Instantiate(particles, hitInfo.point, playerRotation), 0.15f);
}

I tried to make the particles a prefab instead of just a GameObject, which would allow it to still be copied after being destroyed. That didn't do anything.

Your particles reference is of type ParticleSystem which is a component that is attached to a GameObject. The Instantiate() method will return the same object type that was passed in as source. When you pass in a component reference, Instantiate will clone the whole gameobject this component is attached to and returns a reference to the cloned component on the cloned gameobject. You currently pass this component reference to the Destroy method. As a result you will destroy the ParticleSystem component, but the GameObject it was attached to would still remain. You need to destroy the GameObject instead.
You can either instantiate the GameObject of that particle system so Instantiate would return a GameObject reference, or you can use the gameObject property of the cloned particle system to destroy the actual gameobject
GameObject clone = Instantiate(particles.gameObject, hitInfo.point, playerRotation);
Destroy(clone, 0.15f);

or
ParticleSystem clone = Instantiate(particles, hitInfo.point, playerRotation);
Destroy(clone.gameObject, 0.15f);


edit your code
first, define your variables global
then:
// change particles to particles.gameObject
Destroy(Instantiate(particles.gameObject, hitInfo.point,playerRotation), 0.15f);

or:
change ParticleSystem particles; --->
GameObject particles;
